# issue in the query while defining constant for calculation

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here I defined the constants 'sell in' and 'sell out' in both sell in and sell out dataset , so I need to calculate RETAIL_MARGIN and RETAIL_MARGIN_PCT .
the formula I defined in such a way that for 'sell out' it should calculate and for 'sell in' it should represent zero value.

the issue what Iam facing in this is its not taking both the constants its calculating 'sell out' for all that should not happen
it should represent sell in and  sell out

I provide sample tables and result output how it should be

```
SELECT 
    DATA_SOURCE,
    CASE WHEN DATA_DOURCE='SELL OUT' 
    THEN 
        ZEROIFNULL(ROUND(SALES_VOLUME*(SO_PRICE*(1-0.18)-SI_PRICE*(1-0.18)),2)) 
        ELSE 0 END  AS RETAIL_MARGIN,
     CASE WHEN DATA_SOURCE= 'SELL OUT'  
     THEN    
     ZEROIFNULL(ROUND(DIVO(SI_PRICE*(1-0.18),SO_PRICE*(1-0.18))*100,2))  
     ELSE 0 END AS RETAIL_MARGIN_PCT
FROM (
    SELECT 
        SOLD_TO,
        EAN,
        DATA_SOURCE,
        ROUND(DIV0(SUM(SALES_VALUE), SUM(SALES_VOLUME)),2) AS SO_PRICE,
        ROUND(DIV0(SUM(SI_SALES_VALUE), SUM(SI_SALES_VOLUME)),2) AS SI_PRICE
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            A3SOLD_TO,
            A3.EAN,
            ROUND(DIV0(COALESCE(A3.SALES_VALUE,0),3),2) AS SO_SALES_VALUE,
            ROUND(DIV0(COALESCE(A3.SALES_VOLUME,0),3),2) AS SO_SALES_VOLUME,
            ROUND(DIV0(ZEROIFNULL( A4.SI_SALES_VALUE),3),2) AS SI_SALES_VALUE,
            ROUND(DIV0(ZEROIFNULL( A4.SI_SALES_VOLUME),3),2) AS SI_SALES_VOLUME
        FROM (
            SELECT
                A1.SOLD_TO,
                A2.EAN,
                A1.DATA_SOURCE,
                ROUND(ZEROIFNULL(SUM(A1.SALES_VALUE)),2) AS SALES_VALUE,
                ROUND(ZEROIFNULL(SUM(A1.SALES_VOLUME)),2) AS SALES_VALUE
            FROM (
                SELECT 
                    SOLD_TO,
                    PRODUCT_CD,
                    MAX(CALDAY) AS MAX_DATE,
                    MAX(CALDAY)-90 AS MIN_DATE,
                FROM RGM_SALES_GBL.INT_TXN.SELLOUT
                WHERE SALE_ORG = '7140' 
                    AND PRODUCT_CD IS NOT NULL
                GROUP BY 1,2
            )A5
            JOIN (
                SELECT 
                    SOLD_TO,
                    PRODUCT_CD,
                    CALDAY,
                    'SELL OUT' AS DATA_SOURCE,
                    ROUND(COALESCE(SUM(SALESVALUE),0),2) AS SALES_VALUE,
                    ROUND(COALESCE(SUM(SALESCASE),0),2) AS SALES_VOLUME,
                FROM RGM_SALES_GBL.INT_TXN.SELLOUT
                WHERE SALE_ORG='7140'
                    AND PRODUCT_CD IS NOT NULL
                GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
            )AS A1
                ON A5.SOLD_TO = A1.SOLD_TO 
                    AND A1.PRODUCT_CD=A5.PRODUCT_CD 
                    AND A1.CALDAY BETWEEN A5.MIN_DATE AND A5.MAX_DATE 
             INNER JOIN (
                SELECT DISTINCT 
                    EAN, 
                    PRODUCT_CD
                FROM RGM_SALES_GBL.INT_MD.DIM_PRODUCT 
                WHERE SALES ORG='7140' 
                    AND EAN != ' ' 
                    AND PRODUCT_CD IS NOT NULL 
                    AND BASE_UOM = 'CS'
            ) AS A2
                ON A1.PRODUCT_CD = A2.PRODUCT_CD 
            GROUP BY 1,2
        ) AS A3
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                SOLD_TO,
                EAN,
                MAX(CALDAY) AS MAX_DATE,
                MAX(CALDAY)-90 AS MIN_DATE,
            FROM RGM_SALES_GBL.INT_TXN.SELLIN
            WHERE SALES_ORG='7140' 
                AND COUNTRY_CD= '4025' 
                AND PRODUCT_CD IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY 1,2
        )A6
        (
            SELECT 
                SOLD_TO,
                EAN,
                CALDAY,
                'SELL IN' AS DATA_SOURCE,
                ROUND(ZEROIFNULL(SUM(NET_INV_VALUE_IN_LC)),2) AS SI_SALES_VALUE,
                ROUND(ZEROIFNULL(SUM(SALESCASES)),2) AS SI_SALES_VOLUME
            FROM RGM_SALES_GBL.INT_TXN.SELLIN
            WHERE SOLD_TO NOT IN ( 
                SELECT DISTINCT 
                    SOLD_TO FROM 
                FROM RGM_SALES_GBL.INT_TXN.SELLOUT
                WHERE SALE_ORG='7140'
                    AND PRODUCT_CD IS NOT NULL
                )
                AND SALES_ORG = '7140' 
                AND COUNTRY_CD = '4025'
            GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
        )A4
            ON A4.SOLD_TO = A6.SOLD_TO 
                AND A4.EAN = A6.EAN 
                AND A4.CALDAY BETWEEN A6.MIN_DATE AND A6.MAX_DATE 
        ON A3.SOLD_TO = A4.SOLD_TO 
            AND A3.EAN=A4.EAN
    )
    GROUP BY 1,2
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE RGM_SALES_GBL.INT_TXN.SELLOUT
    (SOLD_TO INT,
    EAN INT ,
    PRODUCT_CD INT,
    CALDAY   DATE
    SALESVALUE INT, 
    SALESCASE  INT,
    SALE_ORG INT,)
    
    VALUES(123,10001,101,5/1/2021,76,35,'7140),
    (123,10002,102,5/20/2021,21,15,'7140),
    (124,10003,103,6/15/2021,45,14,'7140),
    (123,10004,101,6/02/2021,76,43,'7140)
```

```
CREATE TABLE RGM_SALES_GBL.INT_TXN.SELLIN
    (SOLD_TO INT,
    EAN INT ,
    CALDAY   DATE
    NET_INV_VALUE_IN_LC INT, 
    SALESCASES  INT,
    SALES_ORG INT,
    COUNTRY_CD INT)
    
    VALUES(201,10001,5/1/2021,15,30,'7140','4025'),
    (203,10002,5/20/2021,43,49,'7140','4025'),
    (204,10003,6/15/2021,38,15,'7140','4025'),
    (205,10005,6/02/2021,61,56,'7140','4025')
```

```
CREATE TABLE RGM_SALES_GBL.INT_MD.DIM_PRODUCT
    (EAN INT,
    PRODUCT_CD INT,
    BASE_UOM  STRING)
    
    VALUES(10001,1001,'CS'),(10002,103,'CS'),(10004,104,'CS')
```

| DATA_SOURCE | RETAIL_MARGIN | RETAIL_MARGIN_PCT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SELL OUT | 76 | 15 |
| SELL OUT | 98 | 13.5 |
| SELL IN | 0 | 0 |
| SELL IN | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Hi - I'm guessing that 75% of that SQL is not directly relevant to your question; you are more likely to get a useful response if you give a minimal reproducible example rather than expecting someone to wade through a lot of code to try and work out which bits are relevant to your question. Also, please provide some sample data and the result you want to achieve based on that data (by updating your question with editable text)

Comment: Hi- as you said I edited  it and provided sample tables and expected output , with my query the output is not getting as expected

Comment: it appears you want to UNION ALL your `sellin` and `sellout` data together, not join it..

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim If I do union all it will work, but Iam grouping based on the sold_to and EAN that I cant do with union all and the expected output will not give. Is any other way we can do ?